# Missing config option from Linux .config

Tags: linux, bpf, kbuild

I am trying to set the `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF` option to `y` in my Linux `.config` file. For some reason, this config item is missing from `.config` even after running `make olddefconfig`, and when I manually add `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y` to `.config`, the option is removed as soon as I run `make`. What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an option is omitted from `.config` (and when it is removed from `.config` by the build process automatically), this is the same as not having the option set.

Take a look at the Kconfig file where the option is originally defined. The option must have dependencies on other config options and these dependencies are not met, which is why the option is being automatically removed from `.config` by the build process.

`DEBUG_INFO_BTF` is defined in `lib/Kconfig.debug`. Here is the definition:

```
config DEBUG_INFO_BTF
  bool "Generate BTF typeinfo"
  depends on !DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT && !DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED
  depends on !GCC_PLUGIN_RANDSTRUCT || COMPILE_TEST
  help 
    Generate deduplicated BTF type information from DWARF debug info.
    Turning this on expects presence of pahole tool, which will convert
    DWARF type info into equivalent deduplicated BTF type info.
```

`DEBUG_INFO_BTF` depends on the `DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT` option being turned off. In my `.config` file, `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT` was set to `y`, which is why `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y` was being removed automatically by the build process (and why the option was omitted originally from my `.config` file). Unsetting the `DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT` option fixed my issue.

Comment: Is there perhaps a tool that would go through dependencies and explain why a certain option got set or not set?

Comment: @DimaTisnek I'm not aware of such a tool off the top of my head. However, you could implement a simple algorithm to figure this out.

Comment: Maybe I will :) I couldn't find anything ready-made...